# Active Admin Custom Action Item Resource Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, activeadmin

Don't know why I can't seem to figure this out since it seems like it should be so simple, but basically, I'm trying to create a link to an action (I want "Publish" to appear next to show, edit, delete) for each of a resource in Active Admin.

I used the code they suggest on their wiki:

```
 action_item do
    link_to "button label", action_path(post)
 end
```

Problem is, I get an error because rails doesn't know what "post" is.  It's nil.  The version of the Wiki on Github has the same code, except they use "resource" instead of post.  I wasn't sure if that was them implying that I would use my own resource name there, or if you're supposed to actually use the variable "resource".  I tried the latter case and got a "Couldn't find without an ID" error.

So the question is, where do I set the variable name?  What are they using as their iterator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used to use this:

```
action_item only: :show do |resource|
  link_to('New Post', new_resource_path(resource))
end
```

UPDATE

```
action_item only: :show do
  link_to('New Post', new_resource_path)
end
```

Thanks [Alter Lagos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895789/alter-lagos)

Comment: Solved this a while ago and forgot to close out the question. I believe this ended up being my solution. Didn't realize the block expected a variable

Comment: @StephenCorwin This is returning an `ActiveAdmin::Views::ActionItems` object (with active_admin 0.6), which has nothing to do with the used model. The correct answer should be what's @LuisOrtegaAraneda has explained.

Answer (score 7):

I have accomplished this with a very similar piece of code, see:

Inside my: `app/admin/posts.rb`

```
member_action :publish, method: 'get' do
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.publish!
  redirect_to admin_post_path(post), notice: 'Post published!'
end
```

In my case, I want the link buttons available only in the `show` action.

```
action_item :only => :show do
  if post.status == 'pending' 
    link_to 'Publish', publish_admin_post_path(post)
  elsif post.status == 'published'
    link_to 'Expire', expire_admin_post_path(post)
  else
  end
end
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 7):

In ActiveAdmin you have to use `resource` to reference an object that you're working with.

When you use `resource` in an action like `index`, you will probably get an error as ActiveAdmin is not working with one. To prevent this, specify the actions you want the button to appear in.

To specify an action, give the argument `only` with an array of the actions you want the button to appear in. For example:

```
action_item :only => [:show, :edit] do
  ...
end
```